# Remove Cache-Control headers from AWS CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm setting Cache-Control:s-maxage=3600 from my Origin server. By this I'm instructing my AWS CloudFront to cache the content for 3600 seconds. I have white listed some cookies and set caching based on the cookie values in CloudFront. This setup is working fine until there is no proxy in between the client and my CloudFront.

If there is Proxy, It also caches a version due to s-maxage header without considering the cookie value. Due to this my end users are seeing irrelevant versions of my web page.

Is there any way to overcome this? Or I need to write a Lambda@edge function to remove this Cache-Control:s-maxage=3600 in Viewer Response?

Comment: Why not remove the `Cache-Control` header from the origin and set the CloudFront `Default TTL` to 3600?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Cache life time is dynamic and set by origin server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Lamda@Edge function at Viewer Response and reset the Cache-Control header.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    /* Get response */
    const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;       

    response.headers['cache-control'] = [{
        key: 'cache-control', value: 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
    }];

    callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: Curious - why Lambda@Edge and not Cloudfront functions?

Comment: @Dorian, CloudFrount Functions were not available at the time.

Comment: would you use CF today vs Lambda@Edge if given the option?

Comment: Sure, now I can try CF Functions @Dorin